# Javascript?/CSS - Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, css

I was looking for some kind of code similar to Gmail's Chat on Gmail's Page: a drop-down menu that pushes everything else that is down to the chat, but for some reason I couldn't see the page's source and I haven't found the same code in any other page. Does anybody know some page with similar code?

Regards!

Comment: Hi, I don't understand "pushes everything else that is down to the chat". Regarding Gmail, like many sites now its JavaScripts are heavily compiled and minimized (if not actively obfuscated) so it will be very difficult to reverse engineer. I'd recommend something like Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools if you do want to attempt it however.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really didn't know how to explain exactly what I wanted. If you take a look at Gmail's page (at least with default configuration), there's an "Invite Friend" menu under the chat menu. When you click on the chat, it pushes the Invite menu. That was the effect I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's native slideDown function to show hidden elements that will push content down below them, depending on your slideDown element's CSS positioning and float.

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a  which height is set to 0px or auto to make it expand/collapse.

You can also give a sliding effect by gradually increasing/decreasing the height of the div.

As long as it's not positioned absolute, it will push the content below.